# Possible to use cloud function to download video onto Firebase server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to use write a cloud function to download a video file. I will do something like below to save the file into a mp4 format file.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("video.mp4");
const request = http.get("http://my-video-server.com/nice-day.mp4", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

But I am wondering where is the file saved? Is it somewhere under `/tmp` on the firebase server? Can I specify the path for downloading the file? Also, if the video size is several GB, does firebase has any limit about how we use your server?

The reason I want to download a video file is I want to use the file to upload to YouTube via Youtube's API. They don't support upload via a link, it has to be a physical file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only** writable path in Cloud Functions is /tmp.  It's a memory-based filesystem, so you will only have a very limited amount of space available.  I suggest reading the documentation on the [Cloud Functions execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec).

You can specify the exact file of the download using the API of the modules you're using for the download.

Cloud Functions is not a suitable product for work that requires large amount of disk space or memory.

Comment: Regarding the space limit, does it have any absolute number, like 1GB? Also, is /tmp shared or dedicated?

Comment: Yes, it uses whatever memory limit you've chosen for the function.  I suggest reading the documentation on that as well.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I saw the max limit is 2GB. Is it for a single cloud function or shared by all functions?

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty clear that you set it per function. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: Thanks for confirming Doug! Btw, is there any disadvantage of setting the max 2GB limit? If not, every function should have the max limit, right?

Comment: I don't have an opinion about that.  Configure whatever you need.

Comment: Never mind Doug! It's really helpful! Thanks again!